# Recursive power function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having some trouble with this function. The function takes a and computes it to the power of b recursively. My compiler gives me a segmentation error when I compile this, which I'm not sure how to fix. Can anyone help?

```
/****   Recursive power function   > Computes a^b, where b can be positive or negative*****/
        int recPower(double a, int b)
        {   
            if (b == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return (a *recPower(a, b-1));
            }
          }

/* Computes a^b (power function) */    
cout << "POWER" << endl;    
cout << "----------" << endl;    
int a = 2, b = -3;    
cout << a << "^" << b << " = ";    
cout << recPower(a, b) << endl;    
cout << endl;
```

Comment: `return (a *recPower(a, b-1));` That won't work when `b` is negative. Try it on paper to see why.

Comment: If you get a segmentation error when trying to compile, that suggests a compiler bug.  Perhaps you meant that you get a segmentation error when you try to run the compiled program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is a result of infinite recursion. `b` never reaches 0 since you keep decrementing it on every recursive step.

You probably need to insert this clause into your code:

```
if (b < 0)
{
    return 1.0 / recPower(a,-b);
} 
else if (b == 0)
...
```

Of course, a to the power of a negative number will more sure be a value between 0 and 1, which is hard to reflect accurately if your return type is int.  That's an exercise left up to you to reconcile. `recPower` should probably return a double type if the input parameter is a double.

Answer (score 0):

As divx commented, the problem is that your funtion doesn't work well with negative expontents: it enters in an infinite recursion (not exactly infinite, but it causes an stack overflow).

Other thing, is that if the base is `double` or you want to process negative exponents, then the function should return a `double`.

This will do the work:

```cpp
double recPower(double a, int b)
{
    if (b < 0)
    {
        return 1.0/recPower(a, -b);
    }
    else if (b == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return (a *recPower(a, b-1));
}
```

Output for your example:

```
POWER
----------
2^-3 = 0.125
```